# In .Net 2.0 :How Can I form a predicate delegate to Find() something in my List<T>?

Tags: c#-2.0

After looking on MSDN, it's still unclear to me how I should form a proper predicate to use the Find() method in List using a member variable of T (where T is a class)
For example:

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public String Address;
    public string Designation;
}

String[] input = new string[] { "VinishGeorge", "PonKumar", "MuthuKumar" };
//ConCatenation of FirstName and Lastname

List<Name> lstName = new List<Name>();

Name objName = new Name();
// Find the first of each Name whose FirstName and LastName will be equal to input(String array declard above).

for(int i =0;i<lstName.Count;i++)
{
    objName = lstName .Find(byComparison(x));
    Console.Writeline(objName .Address + objName.Designation);
}
```

What should my `byComparison` predicate look like?

Comment: It would really help if you would format your code more sensibly and make it closer to "real" code (public not Public, for not For etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear why you're looping *and* calling `Find`. Normally you'd call `Find` *not* in a loop - it will loop for you. Anonymous methods are your friends here though:

```
Name found = lstName.Find(delegate(Name name) {
                              return name.FirstName + name.LastName == x;
                          });
```

If you're using C# 3 (even targeting .NET 2) you can use a lambda expression instead:

```
Name found = lstName.Find(name => name.FirstName + name.LastName == x);
```

EDIT: To find all names in `input` you can use:

```
List<Name> matches = lstName.FindAll(delegate(Name name) {
                               string combined = name.FirstName + name.LastName;
                               return input.Contains(combined);
                           });
```

Note that this won't be terribly efficient as it will look through the whole of `input` for a match on *every* `Name`. However, the more efficient alternatives are more complicated - I think it's important for you to understand how this code works to start with.

Comment: @RajeshKumarG: Well I've shown you code which does it for *one* particular input - so presumably you just want to loop over `input` (*not* over `lstName` as per your question) and call `Find` with the appropriate value each time.

Comment: Is it possible by using it through lstName.FindAll() ? If so, Can you please tell me the solution?

Comment: @RajeshKumarG: Yes, it's possible... but you asked about Find, which is why I gave an answer with that... See my edit.